# Detect array with issue (Debug mode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, swift

My app is crushing when i'm calling a few methods

I can see the error message and I understand what it say but I don't know how to detect the array with the problem by the message.
I have lots of arrays in the project.
how can I know from where the problem come from?

this is the message:

```
2014-12-16 15:07:01.830 myApp[2776:1237923] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2a3eae3f 0x37a98c8b 0x2a2ffc49 0x114c07 0x2d8e515d 0x2d8e3835 0x2d8df47d 0x2d885b37 0x2d2adccd 0x2d2a96b5 0x2d2a953d 0x2d2a8f21 0x2d2a8d25 0x2d2a2bfd 0x2a3b15cd 0x2a3aec8b 0x2a3af093 0x2a2fd621 0x2a2fd433 0x316ab0a9 0x2d8e7809 0x12fee5 0x38018aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: are u initialize the array?

Comment: why not post the methods you called?

Comment: Xcode provided us a vital feature called - "Break Points". Use it.

Comment: I know what is "Break Points" - but in this case i cant use it because this issue comes only when i'm typing text very fast.

Comment: @vishnu - yes the array is initialize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle All exceptions, From Xcode click on **Show the Breakpoint Navigator**

Click `+` button at bottom side and from pop up click on **Add Exception Breakpoint.**

[image]

This will add exception break points for application, try to run again and execution will stop if any runtime  exception raised.

[image]

If this will not help, enable zombie environment for project, check out from this thread -

**[How to set exception breakpoint from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560560/how-to-set-the-exception-breakpoint-in-xcode-6/27560962#27560962)**

Answer (score 1):

Enable Zombie Object in Xcode for better error tracing.

To enable

- Press Command+Option+R
- Under Diagnostic tab-> Memory Management
- Check "Enable Zombie Object"

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks - i did it now but the app crush like always. what is this thing do?

Comment: Please go through this http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2 , this will help you