# My app crashes with no error message how can I find out where this comes from?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hi I am working on an app witch worked great yesterday and when I re opened the project today and launched it on the simulator, my app crashed with no error message, how could I find out where the problem comes from? I added a screenshot of when my app craches. Please note that I have seen some similar questions on here that did not solve my problem[image: this is the screenshot of when my app crashes]

Comment: you can get your exception message through the log messages , write it here so people could help you

Comment: The error message is: "signal SIGABT". Look in the "Report Navigator" Xcode command-8 for details.

Comment: The debug area is empty @AbdAl-rhmanTaherBadary

Comment: What could that mean? it just says "no logs" @zaph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after doing some research I realized that the "signal SIGABRT" was a connection problem so I went to the main storyboard, and to the connections inspector and I had some connections with a "!" so I deleted them and the app works great again ! I suspect it was because of some connections I deleted by error and reconnected either way if your having this issue be sure to check the connections inspector and delete all connections with a "!"

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions to try and track down the source of the crash:

- [Add an Exception Breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27505675/1530368) on "All Exceptions"
- [Enable Zombie Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27560962/1530368) in your project's Debug Scheme to see if you're sending a message to a de-allocated object

Try the two debugging steps separately (first enable Exception Breakpoint then enable Zombie Objects.)
Have you also tried cleaning the project and deleting/re-installing app from Simulator?

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I have just tried all of the above and it doesn't seem to have changed anything, when I select Diagnostics tab. And mark Enable Zombie Objects the box says it is in obj-c and I am in swift , could this be part of the problem?

Comment: My bad. I don't believe Zombie Objects works in Swift. Did you possibly make any modifications to your main view controller in the StoryBoard? Try adding a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad()` for the main view controller to see if the app is even getting there

Comment: I dont think I made any modifications to the main view, and I tried the breakpoint and it doesn't get there

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the action handlers are properly linked up to your objects in MainStoryboard.  e.i. if you look at your ViewController and find your object definition

```
@IBOutlet weak var sampleTextBox: UILabel!
```

It should have a circle to the left of this line of code.  These circles should be filled in if everything is properly connected.  If you see empty circles then these lines are not connected to objects properly.  You will need to reconnect these lines to the Objects in the Storyboard by right clicking on the circle and dragging to the object in question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, everything is linked up.