# Debugging Crash in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have an application & I am debugging that after some time I am getting below message in console logs

**Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 3
Program ended with exit code: 0**

Can anyone help me in telling about this signal 3 log & how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Set an Exception Breakpoint to find out more. Here is how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27505675/1457385

Comment: @shallowThought Exception Breakpoint is not helping in this case. I already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me in telling about this signal 3 log & how can I get rid of this?

You'll generally also get a stack trace and probably a lot of other information. You may need to scroll in the console to see it. The stack trace will show you what methods were executing at the point when the crash happened, and there's typically also some indication of what kind of error occurred.

Comment: I usually got other stack trace but in this particular case there is no stack trace & no information.

Answer (score 0):

This could have several issues, but probably it will be a memory issue. Try to use Instruments to cover that problem.

1. Ctrl-click on our Xcode Icon in the Dock
2. Open Developer Tool
3. Instruments
4. Select Leaks (or at least Allocations)
5. Select your app and start the measurement 
   [image: Start Leak checks on instruments]